# Is it good to use webpack in angular 6 and above or is it handled by ng-build prod?

Tags: angular, performance, webpack

I want to improve performance of the application. I've splitted app into modules and implemented lazy loading. I want to now compress the images and do further more optimization. Should I use webpack to minify the js or is it handled by build prod?

Comment: read this https://v6.angular.io/guide/universal

Answer (score 0):

Angular can minify the JS for you. If you want to still combine Webpack with Angular 6 this article may help you.
https://medium.com/@anandshende1994/angular-6-with-webpack-9e7d6e7dc5fc